# Cake Build - Update NuGet package to the newest version

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, cakebuild

I have a solution with 5 projects in it. Every project is deployed via a nuget-push. Some projects reference other projects via nuget. In order to work properly these nuget-packages have to be updated before they are pushed.

For this we use Cake-Build but the nuget update is not working on core/standard projects. Instead it is necessary to use remove --> add, which is not working for me?

How can I handle this?

Example:

- Project A v1.0.0
- Project B v1.0.0
- Project C v1.0.0

  - Reference to A v1.0.0
  - Reference to B v1.0.0

Now the Build-Script would compile A and B, increment the version to v1.0.1, and push the nuget-package. Before C is build the nuget packages to A & B needs to be updated.

Example:

- Project A v1.0.1
- Project B v1.0.1
- Project C v1.0.1

  - Reference to A **v1.0.1**
  - Reference to B **v1.0.1**

How I'm able to update the packages via Cake-Build?!?

Comment: A dedicated tool like `dotnet-outdated` might be a better option, https://github.com/jerriep/dotnet-outdated#upgrading-packages

Answer (score 2):

If you use project references and build as part of same solution, you should be able to get everything referenced correctly. That's how Cake itself is built.

- Cake.exe / dll depends on

  - Cake.Core
  - Cake.Common which depends on

    - Cake.Core

When we i.e. build `0.30.0` we pass that version as common MSBuildSettings to Restore. Build and Pack. Rough example

```
string configuration = "Release",
       version = "0.30.0",
       semVersion = "0.30.0"; // for pre-release this is suffixed i.e. -alpha-001

DotNetCoreMSBuildSettings msBuildSettings = new DotNetCoreMSBuildSettings()
                            .WithProperty("Version", semVersion)
                            .WithProperty("AssemblyVersion", version)
                            .WithProperty("FileVersion", version);


DotNetCoreRestore("./src/Cake.sln", new DotNetCoreRestoreSettings
{
    Verbosity = DotNetCoreVerbosity.Minimal,
    Sources = new [] { "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" },
    MSBuildSettings = msBuildSettings
});

DotNetCoreBuild("./src/Cake.sln", new DotNetCoreBuildSettings()
{
    Configuration = configuration,
    NoRestore = true,
    MSBuildSettings = msBuildSettings
});

var projects = GetFiles("./src/**/*.csproj");

foreach(var project in projects)
{
    DotNetCorePack(project.FullPath, new DotNetCorePackSettings {
        Configuration = configuration,
        OutputDirectory = "./nuget,
        NoBuild = true,
        NoRestore = true,
        IncludeSymbols = true,
        MSBuildSettings = msBuildSettings
    });
```

}

A project reference in .NET Core csproj looks like

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Cake.Core\Cake.Core.csproj" />
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but the project C which has a project-reference to A behaves different to a nuget-reference A to C or?